# rsDriver function returning $id is NA

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to use `Rselenium` for webscraping and have not had success being able to open a browser. After working through several other issues, I am now encountering a new one. Here is the code I have been using:

```r
driver  <- rsDriver(remoteServerAddr="localhost", browser = "chrome", 
            chromever = "109.0.5414.74", port=9515L)
server  <- driver$server
browser <- driver[["client"]] 
browser$navigate(url)
```

Following the `rsDriver` function, I get the following output:

```r
checking Selenium Server versions:`
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD`
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$id
[1] NA
```

The `driver$server` and `browser <- driver[["client"]]` lines run without error. Following the `browser$navigate(url)` function I get NULL. When I run `server$log()` I get the following output:

I have `RSelenium` v1.7.9, wdman v0.2.6, and am using selenium-server-4.8.1. I have windows 10. In addition to running the code, I also opened chromedriver manually and am trying to run the driver on the port shown in the chromedriver window. I have not been able to find anyone with the same error as of yet, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach which works well :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
url <- "www.a_url.com"
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
```

With this approach, you have to install Docker. It is very easy to install.